# angular2 routing will not work EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise):

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

angular2 why?

```
 { path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent,canActivate: [AuthFirebaseGuard] },
 { path: 'apikey',      component: ApiKeyComponent, canActivate: [AuthFirebaseGuard],outlet:'content'}
```

In my nav:

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['apikey']">Api Key</a></li>


EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'dashboard/apikey'
```

I event tried:

```
{ path: 'dashboard/apikey',      component: ApiKeyComponent, canActivate: [AuthFirebaseGuard],outlet:'content'}




 <div class="container"> 
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

My nav is in:

I want to target:

```
<router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
```

PS it works if I do the following:

```
  <li ><a (click)="onClick()">Api Key</a></li>

  onClick(){
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard(content:apikey)' );
  }
```

This is what the url looks like:

```
 http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard(content:apikey)
```

How do I format router link?

```
 [routerLink]="['/apikey']" e.g. <li ><a routerLink="['dashboard:(content:apikey)']">Api Key</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think 'apiKey' isn't a child of 'dashboard' so the route is only `/apiKey` not `/dashboard/apikey`

The navigation url should include the outlet. I.e.`....routerLink=['./dashboard:apiKey']`

Comment: if I use the above I get this error:  Cannot match any routes: 'dashboard/%5B'dashboard%3Aapikey'%5D'

Comment: Sorry abt that. Was supposed to be './dashboard:apiKey'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I correctly understand your question ^^

But if you want to display two components on the same url, you can do like this :

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: '', component: ApiComponent, outlet: 'content'}
];
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In your case, you can define like this :

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {pathMatch: 'dashboard/*', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard/apikey', component: ApiComponent, outlet: 'content'},
  {path: 'dashboard/other', component: OtherComponent, outlet: 'content'}
];

<li><a [routerLink]="['dashboard/apikey']">Api Key</a></li>
```